# How to calculate what employees at a factory are "on call" each day and night shift throughout the year?

Tags: java, io, calendar, scheduling

I'm working on my first program in Java that will be used for a practical purpose and I'm stuck--getting an output that isn't correct.

Here is the problem I'm trying to compute: the manufacturing plant I work at operates 24/7, 363 days a year (off Christmas Eve and Christmas) in four day shifts. Each crew works 4 twelve hour days or nights in a row, then gets 4 days off. There are four crews, each works four days, then has four days off, then works four nights, then has four nights off. A Crew and B Crew rotate opposite of each other, and C Crew and D Crew rotate opposite of each other.

While A Crew and B Crew are working, members of C Crew and D Crew are on call in case someone on A or B Crew is absent. There are three classifications of employees: Senior operators, Junior Operators, and Compounders. On each crew, there are four Senior operators, three Junior operators, and 2 Compounders. For the first two days of a four day rotation cycle, three of the Senior operators are on call, while the fourth is not on call. The Senior operator who is not on call during this period rotates: one is not on call each time the others are on call.  For the last two days, the three Junior operators are on call.

For the Senior employees, the previous cycle determines if they are on call for day shifts or night shifts: if the crew that is not working had been working day shifts, the senior operators are on call for the first two day shifts, or vice versa if they had been working nights during the previous cycle. For the Junior operators, the cycle they are about to begin dictates whether they are on call day shifts or night shifts for the second two days off.

The Compounders are on call for the first and fourth days off. Whether they are on call days or nights is determined in the same way as for operators.

My goal is to write a program in Java that calculates which employees are on call for each day and night shift, and output the results to a text file. I am an amateur that has only taken two programming classes thus far, so I am certain that what I have written so far is far less efficient than it could be. I am just trying to figure out why the output is incorrect. My suspicion is that I have either calculated a variable incorrectly or I am missing a piece of the puzzle altogether. Note that the first day of the year for the purposes of the program is January 3rd because the 1st and 2nd were part of the previous year's cycle.

Below is my code. I removed all getters and setters to fit within the allotted length. I appreciate any and all help that can be offered.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class OnCallAug812 {
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
private double cycleDay = ((cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 3)) % 16;
private double dayOfCycle = cycleDay % 4;
// number of days into current rotation ( 0 =4, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3)
private int cycleRotation = (int) (cycleDay / 4);
// number of current rotation (4 per cycle)
private int cycleOfYear = ((cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 3) / 16);
private int onCallCycle = cycleOfYear % 4;


// A crew operators: 4 Senior
private int a1S = 0;
private int a2S = 1;
private int a3S = 2;
private int a4S = 3;

// variables for A crew names
private String a1;
private String a2;
private String a3;
private String a4;

// A Crew Junior Operators represented by one variable b/c
// all are on call or not on call at same time

private int aJr;

// A crew junior operator names
private String aJr1;
private String aJr2;
private String aJr3;

// B crew operators: 4 Senior
private int b1S = 0;
private int b2S = 1;
private int b3S = 2;
private int b4S = 3;

// B crew operator names
private String b1;
private String b2;
private String b3;
private String b4;

// B Crew Junior Operators represented by one variable b/c
// all are on call or not on call at same time

private int bJr;

// B crew operator junior names
private String bJr1;
private String bJr2;
private String bJr3;

// C crew operators: 4 Senior
private int c1S = 0;
private int c2S = 1;
private int c3S = 2;
private int c4S = 3;

// C operator senior names
private String c1;
private String c2;
private String c3;
private String c4;

// C Crew Junior Operators represented by one variable b/c
// all are on call or not on call at same time

private int cJr;

// C crew junior operator names
private String cJr1;
private String cJr2;
private String cJr3;

// D crew operators: 4 Senior
private int d1S = 0;
private int d2S = 1;
private int d3S = 2;
private int d4S = 3;

// d crew senior names
private String d1;
private String d2;
private String d3;
private String d4;

// D Crew Junior Operators represented by one variable b/c
// all are on call or not on call at same time

private int dJr;

// D crew junior operator names
private String dJr1;
private String dJr2;
private String dJr3;

// Call status for each A Crew employee--set to 0,1, or 2
// 0 = on call day shift
// 1 = on call night shift
// 2 = off call
private int a1SCallStat = -1;
private int a2SCallStat = -1;
private int a3SCallStat = -1;
private int a4SCallStat = -1;
private int aJrCallStat = -1;

// Call status for each B Crew employee--set to 0,1, or 2
private int b1SCallStat = -1;
private int b2SCallStat = -1;
private int b3SCallStat = -1;
private int b4SCallStat = -1;
private int bJrCallStat = -1;

// Call status for each C Crew employee--set to 0,1, or 2
private int c1SCallStat = -1;
private int c2SCallStat = -1;
private int c3SCallStat = -1;
private int c4SCallStat = -1;
private int cJrCallStat = -1;

// Call status for each D Crew employee--set to 0,1, or 2
private int d1SCallStat = -1;
private int d2SCallStat = -1;
private int d3SCallStat = -1;
private int d4SCallStat = -1;
private int dJrCallStat = -1;

// Call status for each crew's pelletizer operators (both on or both off)

private int aP;
private int bP;
private int cP;
private int dP;

private String aP1;
private String aP2;
private String bP1;
private String bP2;
private String cP1;
private String cP2;
private String dP1;
private String dP2;

private int aPCallStat = -1;
private int bPCallStat = -1;
private int cPCallStat = -1;
private int dPCallStat = -1;

public int determineCall(double onCallCycle, int crewNumber) {
    double aNumber = (crewNumber + onCallCycle) % 7;
    if (aNumber <= 2) {
        return 0;
    } else if (aNumber >= 3 && aNumber < 6) {
        return 1;
    } else if (aNumber == 6) {
        return 2;
    } else
        return -1;
}

public int determineCallJr(double onCallCycle, int crewNumber){
    double aNumber = (crewNumber + onCallCycle) % 7;
    if (aNumber <= 3) {
        return 0;
    } else if (aNumber >= 4 && aNumber <= 6) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return -1;
}

public int determineCallP(double onCallCycle, int crewNumber){
    double aNumber = (crewNumber + onCallCycle) % 7;
    if (aNumber <= 3) {
        return 0;
    } else if (aNumber >= 4 && aNumber <= 6) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return -1;
}

public void calcCall(OnCallAug812 aug1) {
    // Senior employees on call checks
    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 0)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 1) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC4SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD4SCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 1)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 1) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA4SCallStat(2);
        }

        // b crew second rotation
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB4SCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 2)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 1) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setC4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setC4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getC4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setC4SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setD4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setD4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getD4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setD4SCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 3)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 1) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setA4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setA4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getA4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setA4SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB1S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB1SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB1S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB1SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB1S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB1SCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB2S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB2SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB2S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB2SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB2S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB2SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB3S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB3SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB3S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB3SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB3S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB3SCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB4S()) == 0) {
            aug1.setB4SCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB4S()) == 1) {
            aug1.setB4SCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCall(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getB4S()) == 2) {
            aug1.setB4SCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    // Junior Extruder Operators
    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 0)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 2))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setcJrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setcJrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setcJrCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setDjrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setDjrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setDjrCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 1)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 2))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setaJrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setaJrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setaJrCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setbJrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setbJrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setbJrCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 2)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 2))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setcJrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setcJrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setcJrCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setDjrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setDjrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setDjrCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 3)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 2))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setaJrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setaJrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setaJrCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbJr()) == 0) {
            aug1.setbJrCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbJr()) == 1) {
            aug1.setbJrCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallJr(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbJr()) == 2) {
            aug1.setbJrCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 0)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setcPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setcPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setcPCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setdPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setdPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setdPCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 1)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setaPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setaPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setaPCallStat(2);
        }

        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setbPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setbPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setbPCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 2)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setcPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setcPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getcP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setcPCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setdPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setdPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getdP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setdPCallStat(2);
        }
    }

    if ((aug1.cycleRotation == 3)
            && ((aug1.dayOfCycle == 3) || (aug1.dayOfCycle == 0))) {
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setaPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setaPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getaP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setaPCallStat(2);
        }
        if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbP()) == 0) {
            aug1.setbPCallStat(0);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbP()) == 1) {
            aug1.setbPCallStat(1);
        } else if (aug1.determineCallP(aug1.getOnCallCycle(), aug1.getbP()) == 2) {
            aug1.setbPCallStat(2);
        }
    }
}

private String readFile(String pathname) throws Exception {

    File file = new File(pathname);
    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    try {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
        }
        return fileContents.toString();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
}

public void check0(PrintWriter output2, int callStat, String name) {
    if (callStat == 0) {
        output2.print(name);
        output2.println();
    }
}

public void check1(PrintWriter output2, int callStat, String name) {
    if (callStat == 1) {
        output2.print(name);
        output2.println();
    }
}

public void addDate(OnCallAug812 aug1) {
    cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    aug1.cycleDay = ((cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 3)) % 16;
    aug1.dayOfCycle = cycleDay % 4;
    // number of days into current rotation ( 0 =4, 1=1, 2=2, 3=3)
    aug1.cycleRotation = (int) (cycleDay / 4);
    // number of current rotation (4 per cycle)
    aug1.cycleOfYear = ((cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 2) / 16);
    aug1.onCallCycle = cycleOfYear % 4;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OnCallAug812 aug1 = new OnCallAug812();
    aug1.calcCall(aug1);
    System.out.print("Day of 16 day rotation(0 to 15): ");
    System.out.println(aug1.cycleDay);
    System.out.print("Day of 4 day cycle (0 to 3): ");
    System.out.println(aug1.dayOfCycle);
    System.out.print("Cycle of 16 day rotation (0 to 3): ");
    System.out.println(aug1.cycleRotation);
    System.out.print("16 day cycle number (0 to 22): ");
    System.out.println(aug1.cycleOfYear);
    System.out.print("On Call Cycle Number(0 to 6 then repeat): ");
    System.out.println(aug1.onCallCycle);
}

public OnCallAug812() {
    super();
}
```

}

Comment: isnt there a picture to make it clearer? :)

Comment: I could probably scan a PDF of the current on call list tomorrow. It's written by hand right now.

Comment: After looking at your code i think you should have a look into arrays, lists and other data structures. Even if its not related to your problem it can improve your code a lot (by reducing the amount of variables you need by ~90%).

Comment: Definitely. The thought crossed my mind when I was about halfway in, but at this point I just want to get something that reliably produces a correct output.

Comment: Just as a side suggest, I'd look into Joda-Time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for date/time comparison

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try Joda Time in the future. Could my use of Calendar be the root cause for the wrong output?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good OOP project for beginners. That being said you need to design this in an oop style. The first steps in doing this correctly and even getting close to getting the correct answer to design this program using polymorphism.

A) The first step would be to create a class Employee then create sub classes Senior, Junior, and Compound. These classes would contain tracking information on that empolyess last actions (boolean oncall, boolean shift (day night),etc)

B) The next step would be to figure out how you would create a crew probably another class. The crew class can then track factors such as who worked last, the shift they work, who was not on call last etc. The class would contain groups of employees.

This would be the beginning of designing this program correctly. Once you get to this point if you’re still stuck post again and someone will help you move to the next stage.

if you need a example of how to do this you can look at my ProGauge project that does something similar using different types of devices ex: http://www.behance.net/gallery/ProGauge-Project-in-java-JSON-Data-management/4668415 or just find some java polymorphism exampels on the web!